# Exception ignored in thread started by: <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000017C9E2FC1F0>

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Don't know what the problem is. I am not able to run any of my Django servers. Every time gets the same error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvMYL.png)
Tried reinstalling Django,python but always gets same error.

Answer (score 1):

At line 2 in the python-file

`C:\Users\Bit_cracker\Downloads\...\OrganDonationWebApp-master\hospitals\admin.py`

There is a class called `UserAdmin` defined, however it is defined as a child of the `UserAdmin` which is not possible. If you can change that file, make it so that the class doesn't inherit itself, that would be the first step in the right direction.